# Combine 2 PowerShell arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to combine 2 arrays as explained [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/27/powertip-add-two-powershell-arrays-together/) by Microsoft.

```
$Source = 'S:\Test\Out_Test\Departments'
$Array = Get-ChildItem $Source -Recurse

$Array.FullName | Measure-Object # 85
$Array.FullName + $Source | Measure-Object # 86
$Source + $Array.FullName | Measure-Object # 1
```

The following only has 1 item to iterate through:

```
$i = 0
foreach ($t in ($Source + $Array.FullName)) {
    $i++
    "Count is $i"
    $t
}
```

My problem is that if `$Source` or `$Array` is empty, it doesn't generate seperate objects anymore and sticks it all together as seen in the previous example. Is there a way to force it into separate objects and not into one concatenated one?

Comment: `@($Source;$Array.FullName)`

Comment: Yes yes yes!! That's it! Thank you very much PetSerAl, you helped me a lot here!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In PowerShell, the *left-hand side* operand determines the operator overload used, and the *right-hand side* gets converted to a type that satisfies the operation.

That's why you can observe that

`[string] + [array of strings]` results in a `[string]` (Count = 1)
`[array of strings] + [string]` results in an `[array of strings]` (Count = array size + 1)

You can force the `+` operator to perform array concatenation by using the *array subexpression operator* (`@()`) on the left-hand side argument:

```
$NewArray = @($Source) + $Array.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, now I finally understand why this different behavior is happening. For ease of reading I'll use the following `@($Source;$Array.FullName)` as suggested in the comments by PetSerAl.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Whatever floats your boat, glad I was able to teach you something new :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because $Source is a `System.String` and `+` is probably an overloaded for `Concat`. If you cast `$Source` to an array, you will get your desired output:

```
[array]$Source + $Array.FullName | Measure-Object # 86
```

Comment: `+` is not an alias, it's simply overloaded ([operators can be overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.71).aspx) just like methods)

Answer (score 0):

1. Place your elements inside parentheses preceded by a dollar sign.
2. Separate your elements with semicolons.

Applied to the case of the initial question:

```
$($Source; $Array.FullName) | Measure-Object #86
```